# How to NSTableView cell add padding to cell?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, xcode4, nstableview

I've got an NSTableView which stretches from edge to edge on my window, but the data in the cells on the edge of the table really need some padding. The window doesn't look good if I leave a gutter on the edges, so I'd like to try to add some padding inside some of the cells so the data isn't right up against the edge.

I can't find anything in Interface Builder or in the code documentation about adding padding or insets to the cells.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can subclass NSTextFieldCell and override the drawInteriorWithFrame:inView: method to custom draw the string.

```
- (void)drawInteriorWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)controlView
{
    NSRect titleRect = [self titleRectForBounds:cellFrame];
    NSAttributedString *aTitle = [self attributedStringValue];
    if ([aTitle length] > 0) {
        [aTitle drawInRect:titleRect];
    }
}
```

where titleRectForBounds: adds some space

```
- (NSRect)titleRectForBounds:(NSRect)bounds
{
    NSRect titleRect = bounds;

    titleRect.origin.x += 5;
    titleRect.origin.y += 5;

    NSAttributedString *title = [self attributedStringValue];
    if (title) {
        titleRect.size = [title size];
    } else {
        titleRect.size = NSZeroSize;
    }

    // We don't want the width of the string going outside the cell's bounds
    CGFloat maxX = NSMaxX(bounds);
    CGFloat maxWidth = maxX - NSMinX(titleRect);
    if (maxWidth < 0) {
        maxWidth = 0;
    }

    titleRect.size.width = MIN(NSWidth(titleRect), maxWidth);

    return titleRect;
}
```

There's a more full example at http://comelearncocoawithme.blogspot.com/2011/09/custom-cells-in-nstableview-part-1.html

Comment: Thanks for the very complete answer. I find it really disheartening though that the answer to every question for desktop Cocoa has been "it doesn't do that, you'll need to override the method in a subclass." How is iOS/Cocoa Touch so much more mature than desktop Cocoa?

Comment: I think Cocoa Touch is done so that it is less generic than Cocoa, placing more pre-defined behaviours and policy on controls so that there is a more consistent experience. Cocoa, on the other hand, in trying to be a more general purpose toolkit has some things that while possible, you'll need to write some more code for.

Comment: You also need to remember, NSTableView was likely written 10 or more years ago and so needs and UI desires have changed over that time. I suspect this is why Lion now has the ability to put a custom NSView as the cell. At least in Cocoa, when you need to override a behaviour it's usually quite a simple thing to do

Answer (score 0):

**Easy way**: add spaces before your text strings.
**Better way**: embed a view inside your cell and put all other UI objects inside that.

Comment: Adding spaces was the very first thing I tried. NSTableView appears to trim the strings, removing all leading and trailing spaces before actually displaying, because if I added @"   ", it didn't show, but if I appended @"    _" it would show.

Comment: I've used something like @"   text" successfully, so guess space before text works? Btw these tips were for simple cases. For more complex layouts I've created a XIB with Interface Builder and created a cell based on that. So much easier to make layout changes. Sorry I forgot about this, was late last night.

Answer (score -1):

in your cellforrowAtIndexPath you need to implement this.

cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"   %@",sometext];

or else
take a label and setframe to it.Then add it to cell

Comment: Adding spaces was the very first thing I tried. NSTableView appears to trim the strings, removing all leading and trailing spaces before actually displaying, because if I added @"   ", it didn't show, but if I appended @"    _" it would show.

Comment: Also, I'm dealing with NSTableView, not UITableView. This is desktop Cocoa, not Cocoa Touch on iPhones.